# What is the teststackoverflow site for?

Tags: discussion

My Firefox keeps telling me there are extra secure certificates pulled in, as well as a frame and icons. What is this `teststackoverflow.com` site for, and will I miss any SE functionality by blocking it?

Comment: I asked the same thing on MSO a while back: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267143/whats-teststackoverflow-com-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: @JonK - thanks. Wish there were something like "cross-site duplicate" functionality.